# How to create strip around phone case?

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

On the back of the phone case there is white strip [image]

And I have no idea how to create it, I tried few ideas and searched online but haven't found any solution.

Comment: From what I could see on the image, this is not a *strip*, but actually the rim of a white sheet that is covered by another black sheet. If you are going for realism, you should also model it that way. Perhaps start with a plane and some loop cuts.

Comment: and then what should I do?